# FilteredTextBox in Lift?

Tags: scala, filter, textbox, lift

I'm looking for a `filteredTextBox` in lift to block users from inserting wrong input types.

Something like this Ajax example: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Someone knows something similar in lift or knows if `SHtml.ajaxText` has some Attribute to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting HTML5 capable browsers, `SHtml` has outputs for specific types - like `SHtml.number(...)` and `SHtml.range(...)`. You can accomplish the same thing using `SHtml.ajaxText(label, func, "type" -> "number")` (or `"type" -> "range"`, etc...).

To target other browsers (or for more robust functionality), `JQuery` might be your best bet. You could write your own validation function to get called, or googling quickly found [this library](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input) which looks like it would work (though there must be others too). Based on their documentation, to use it, it looks like you'd just need to do this:

**Snippet:**

```
//add a class for the type (in this case to validate lowercase)
".lc-input" #> SHtml.ajaxText(label, func, "class" -> "validate-this-lowercase")
```

**Template:**

```
//Add this into a processed template - head_merge should add to the head of the document

<head_merge>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $(".validate-this-lowercase").filter_input({regex:'[a-z]'});
    });
  </script>
</head_merge>
<span class="lc-input"></span>
```